Numerical search for interesting lines with python-chess- engine optimization
I'm trying to write a numerical tool for searching interesting chess lines with python. In every node of a search tree (every node corresponds to a chess position) i need to get the engine evaluation and few of the best candidatate moves. The problem I encountered, is that the engine needs a lot of time to return reasonable answer. However, my intuition tells me it should be possible to optimize it because the engine performs the search of lines itself, so after evaluating a certain position, it should be much faster to evaluate the next one after some move.
For example when i get the evaluation of a position for depth 20 and i make lets say third best move and want to evaluate the new position, then I should have already evaluation with depth 19 and it should be fast to add the next layer, rather than evaluating the position from scratch.
Do you have any clues how to take advantage of the prior engine search?

Maybe try increasing hash size UCI settings.
